# How to avoid obserseChanges firing more than once with multiple Meteor processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This is a scenario I have and cannot find a clear answer how to avoid observeChanges firing multiple times.

I have this code listening to a player's command, and fire an event to trigger AI to simulate a move:

```
// Client-side
Deps.autorun(function() {
    var query = Games.find({
        "playerOne": "PlayerOne",
        "playerTwo": "Computer"
    });
    var handle = query.observeChanges({
        changed: function (id, fields) {
            // AI makes a move
            if (fields.playerTurn == "ComputerTurn" && fields.lastplay)
            // lastplay is a timestamp after player has played a turn
                Meteor.call("playComputerTurn", id);
        }
    });
});

//Server-side
Meteor.methods({
    'playComputerTurn': function(id) {
        // long code to simulate a computer turn
     }
});
```

With a single Meteor process, the event only fires once, but running multiple processes, I don't seem to have an option to let observeChanges ignore the events IF a process has already fired once.

*EDIT* to be more clear, the events will need to re-run in case of server restarts and during the server heavy calculation player should not be "halted".

Do I need to wrap the Server-side event with a Fiber in queue, or perhaps I have missed something simple here, could someone please help or suggest?

P.S. If simply placing observeChanges in Server-side, the observe will only run once.

Comment: What changes `playerTurn`?

Comment: @Neil, whenever Computer completes a simulation or Player (a move), `playerTurn` will be updated along with other `Collection` parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you could take. You could call the method using the `update` callback that changes `playerTurn`. Then you wouldn't need an observer at all.

```
// client
Games.update(gameId, {$set: {playerTurn: "ComputerTurn"}}, function (err) {
  if (!err) {
    Meteor.call("playComputerTurn", gameId);
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could do everything in the method that is called when the player takes their turn.

```
// server
Meteor.methods({
  'playComputerTurn': function(gameId) {
    var game = Games.findOne(gameId, ...);

    // make sure this.id is the current player
    // make sure it's this player's turn
    // play turn, set playerTurn, lastplay, etc.
    // long code to simulate a computer turn
  }
});
```

Also note that if you use an observer, it does not need to run inside of an `autorun` unless the selector is reactive.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I did actually try this approach before, but then the player will have to wait the long function completes and will literally "halt" until `playComputerTurn` finishes.
Also, for an extreme scenario, if Server needs to restart for whatever reason, the methods will not run again since `playerTurn` has already been updated to "ComputerTurn".
That's the reason why I choose observeChanges in the first place. I hope it gives a more clear picture

Comment: Ok, you should include this information in your question. To prevent blocking, you can define a stub or pass an asynchronous callback. See [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) for more info. As for server restart, I don't think the observer will work because `playerTurn` would have to change again. Maybe you can set a flag to indicate that the computer has finished its turn and check this on startup.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question, I have now edited the question to reflect this.
I do know how async callback works, but like what I said, if `playerTurn` has updated, the method will not run again after server restarts. If there are 100 games waiting for update in queue, it will be a problem.
In fact observer will run whenever server restarts, if I want observer not to fire during start up, I would do something like this:
`initializing = true;
if (!initializing) {
 //...observer code
}`